# Proving universal sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose A, B and C are sets in a universal set U, Show that:

[image: need to prove both of them]

I tried to solve, but unfortunately the results didn't come up...
I really need some help or guidance...

Comment: Did you try something with the distributive laws and De Morgan's laws?

Comment: Yes, but it is quite tough to understand(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.

$$[A\cap (B\cup C)]\cup[A^c\cap (B\cup C)]\cup (B\cup C)^c=$$

Using the distributive laws:

$$[(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)]\cup[(A^c\cap B)\cup (A^c \cap C)]\cup (B\cup C)^c=$$

Using the commutative laws:

$$[(A\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B)] \cup [(A\cap C)\cup (A^c \cap C)]\cup (B\cup C)^c=$$

Using the distributive laws:

$$[B\cap (A\cup A^c)]\cup [C\cap (A\cup A^c)]\cup (B\cup C)^c =$$

Using the complement laws:

$$[B\cap U]\cup [C\cap U]\cup (B\cup C)^c =$$

Using the identity laws:

$$(B\cup C)\cup (B\cup C)^c=$$

Using the complement laws:

$$=U$$

b.

$$[A\cup (B\cap C)]\cap[A^c\cup (B\cap C)]\cap (B\cap C)^c=$$

Using the distributive laws:

$$[(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)]\cap[(A^c\cup B)\cap (A^c \cup C)]\cap (B\cap C)^c=$$

Using the commutative laws:

$$[(A\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B)] \cap [(A\cup C)\cap (A^c \cup C)]\cap (B\cap C)^c=$$

Using the distributive laws:

$$[B\cup (A\cap A^c)]\cap [C\cup (A\cap A^c)]\cap (B\cap C)^c =$$

Using the complement laws:

$$[B\cup \emptyset]\cap [C\cup \emptyset]\cap (B\cap C)^c =$$

Using the identity laws:

$$(B\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)^c=$$

Using the complement laws:

$$=\emptyset$$